# Having trouble iterating through array please advise

Tags: python

This is my attempt to create a function that reads a user move and adjusts it accordingly in an array. I know there's something simple wrong but I cannot find it.

```
def EnterMove(board):
#
# the function accepts the board current status, asks the user about their move, 
# checks the input and updates the board according to the user's decision
#
    move = int(input("What space would you like to claim? "))

    for row in board:
        for column in row:
           if move == column:
               column = "O"
    return board

board = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

EnterMove(board)
print(board)
```

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is, but reassigning `column` has no effect on the array being iterated. If you want to modify the array, you'll need to iterate the indices of the array and do `board[i][j] = "O"` or something similar.

Comment: `board[row][column] = 'O'`

Comment: Terminology note: you are working with a *list* object, not an array object.

Comment: @Julien That won't work. `row` and `column` are not indexes.

Comment: Yup answered too quickly...

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to `column` doesn't change the contents of the list. You need to get the index and assign that. You can use `enumerate()` to get the indexes and values.

```
    for row in board:
        for i, column in enumerate(row):
           if move == column:
               row[i] = "O"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve. I debugged the code and changed a couple of things. I realize that this is a basic solution but figured that it will be easily readable and traceable. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I hope it helps.

Here is a program that should work if anybody else is having a similar issue and needs help:

```
def EnterMove(board):
#
# the function accepts the board current status, asks the user about their move, 
# checks the input and updates the board according to the user's decision
#
    move = int(input("What space would you like to claim? "))
    row = 0
    while(row<len(board)):
        col = 0
        while(col<len(board[0])):
           if move == 1+row*3+col:
               board[row][col] = "0"
           col+=1
        row+=1
    return board
board = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
board = EnterMove(board)
print(board)
```

One of the issues I noticed is that in the statement array[index], the index has to be an integer, which is not the case in the for loop you were using. I converted to while loops to increase readability and show what wasn't working.

I hope this was helpful.